# Python shelve with already opened file

Tags: python

Is it possible to use shelve with a file that is already opened? I'd like to do something like the following, but shelve.open doesn't accept a file descriptor.

```
 f = open('file.shelve')
 s = shelve.open(f)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shelve is based on [dbm](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/dbm.html#module-dbm), which does not provide an fd interface. Unfortunately, dbm is unlikely to ever provide one, since it relies on the atomicity of `rename` for database consistency.